# CLLocationManager is asynchronous. Having problems with this

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, cllocation

What I'm doing is very simple.

```
class HomeDatasourceController: UICollectionViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
let locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

//CurrentLocation is my variable that isn't changing on time
var currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 5.0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    fetchHomeFeed()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    for currentLocationTemp in locations {
        self.currentLocation = currentLocationTemp
        print("This is latitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude) , and this is longitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    }
}
fetchHomeFeed(){
    print("Hello: ", self.currentLocation)
}
```

When fetchHomeFeed gets called, it only prints out the dummy location that I had it set to (5.0 latitude and longitude) and not my actual location.
I know this is asynchronous, but I'm not sure how to get the call at least ONCE the first time so I can properly print out my location (the first time).

I also need it to continue updating after this because I want to have a live updated of the user's location.

I've tried having fetchHomeFeed() inside the func locationManager, but this prints out ("Hello: ", self.currentLocation) multiple times, and I only want fetchHomeFeed() being called only ONCE (with a proper location), and after this have the location being called continuously as I will have another method using this.

I'm not sure on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation for didUpdateLocations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager):

> **locations**
>
> An array of CLLocation objects containing the location data. This array always contains at least one object representing the current location. If updates were deferred or if multiple locations arrived before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional entries. The objects in the array are organized in the order in which they occurred. Therefore, **the most recent location update is at the end of the array.**

So you do not need to loop through the array of locations, you can just use `locations.last` unless your application needs to worry about deferred location updates.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.last {
        currentLocation = location
    }
}
```

And if you want `fetchHomeFeed` to only be called once there are several options, but simplest is a boolean flag that you check before calling it and you change it the first time it is called.

Comment: I just included my for loop, included a boolean, and included fetchHomeFeed() in that if statement you gave me. Thanks so much! I appreciate the help :)

Comment: I need to also have a constant update for location, in case the user is in a car or something

Comment: I doubt it's useful to do that — if there happen to be multiple updates at once the for loop will go through them so quickly that it's useless to do anything with anything other than the last one. If the user is traveling in a car the system will send discrete location updates when their position changes, as determined by the setup of the location manager. Note you can also specify the [desired accuracy and distance filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager) to ensure you get updates at the frequency you prefer (although the defaults may be fine for you).

Comment: Although for accuracy there's `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` which might be what you want instead of the default (although they recommend only using this if the device is plugged in)

But for the sake of your users' batteries, I would consider carefully whether you actually need such frequent location updates.

Comment: The other locations in the `locations` parameter of the method are, for example, if you cared about the location history of the user, such as an app that tracks your route on a map.

Answer (score 0):

Remove fetchHomeFeed from viewDidLoad. It's not right.

Do this in your locationManager function. This will guarantee that you have a valid location. You stop location manager once you got the valid location and restart if required. If you want to continuously monitor the location then you need to rethink the solution but this will give you an idea.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let location = locations.last else {
               return
        }

        if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
             locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
             locationManager.delegate = nil
             fetchHomeFeed()
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked for the first part of my problem thanks.. I just need to continue getting the location after this though.